# Multiple functions in OpenMP with C

Tags: c, function, parallel-processing, openmp

Suppose I would like to run the functions in parallel.

```
   void foo()
   {
        foo1(args);
        foo2(args);
        foo3(args);
        foo4(args);
   }
```

I want these functions calls run in parallel. How can I run these functions in parallel in OpenMP with C?

Comment: First, you'll need to decide on a *single* language, C or C++; there is no C/C++ language.  For example, the C++ language allows overloaded functions, and the C language doesn't.  The C++ language has function objects, lambdas and smart pointers; the C language doesn't.  Your title says "C" language, yet you tag C++.  Well, which *single* language are your programming in?  Edit your tags as appropriate.

Comment: Functions can be run in parallel as long as they don't share any resources.  If your functions share resources (variables, I/O, etc), consider using separate threads.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the code is running serially when you enter `foo()`, you have a couple of different options.

Option 1: use [sections](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu37.html#x59-1010002.8.1)

```
   void foo()
   {
#pragma omp parallel
     {
#pragma omp sections 
        {
#pragma omp section
          foo1(args);
#pragma omp section
          foo2(args);
#pragma omp section
          foo3(args);
#pragma omp section
          foo4(args);
        }
     }
   }
```

Option 2: use [tasks](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu46.html#x70-2000002.10.1)

```
   void foo()
   {
#pragma omp parallel
     {
#pragma omp single 
        {
#pragma omp task
          foo1(args);
#pragma omp task
          foo2(args);
#pragma omp task
          foo3(args);
#pragma omp task
          foo4(args);
        }
     }
   }
```

Tasks are the more modern way of expressing this, and, potentially, allow you more freedom in controlling the execution.